# No configuration file found and no installation code available. Exiting… in joomla 3.4.8

Tags: php, installation, content-management-system, joomla3.4

How to resolve this in joomla 3.4.8 No configuration file found and no installation code available. Exiting...

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps for localhost environment:

->Please give permission to your Joomla directory is must.
for Ubuntu you can use below command
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/jm348